# Script to archieve mp3 and mp4 files with comparison

Tags: bash, shell, copy, except

I have a folder (call it testdir) with many different file types in subfolders. There are many files with the same name but different extension, even files with the same name/extension (but may not identical). 
I need a script that archives only the mp3 and mp4 files from testdir and its subfolders to an archive folder (without put them in subfolders). If the archieve folder does not exist, create it.
BUT 
- copy only the .mp4 files that has no .mp3 (with the same name)
- compare the .mp3 files if there are more with the same name and copy the ones               are not identical and rename them 
- copy the .mp4 files  (only) that has no .mp3 (with the same name)
The script need to has 2 arguments so it should work like: arch source_dir archive_dir, and display error message if the user use it wrong. Also if the source_dir is not existing.
Here is what I got so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#declare variables
SOURCE_DIR=$1
ARCHIEVE_DIR=$2
#if the user forgets to use 2 arguments:
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then echo Usage: arch source_dir archieve_dir
fi
#if the source_dir does not exist:
if [ ! -d $SOURCE_DIR ]
then echo ERROR: Source directory is missing!
fi
# if archieve_dir does not exist, create it 
if [ ! -d $ARCHIEVE_DIR ]
then mkdir $ARCHIEVE_DIR
fi
echo $ARCHIEVE_DIR created.
cd $ARCHIEVE_DIR
find . -type f \( -iname "*.mp3" -o -iname "-.mp4" \)
# copy all the .mp4 files that have no .mp3 pairs (with the same name)
#copy .mp3 files that have .mp4 identicals (leave mp4s)
# copy and rename the .mp3 files that are not identical but have the same name
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated! THANKS in advance

Comment: Sorry I have just noticed, in the title I entered the wrong filetypes. I am looking for mp3 and mp4 archieving.

Comment: You can edit your own questions, just click the little edit-link below the question

Answer (score 0):

For your first requirement you could go through all the mp4 files in a loop and test each of them:

```
#!/bin/bash
# .. your parameter checks ..

# copy all the .mp4 files that have no .mp3 pairs (with the same name)
for file in $(find . -type f -iname "*.mp4")
do 
  filemp3=$(echo $file | sed s'/.$/3/')
  if [[ $(find . -type f -iwholename $filemp3|wc -l) == 0 ]] ; then
    cp $file $ARCHIVE_DIR/
  fi 
done
```

For the second requirement, would it be sufficient just to copy all mp3's:

```
# copy .mp3 files that have .mp4 identicals (leave mp4s)
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec cp -t $ARCHIVE_DIR/ {} +
```

Your third requirement I don't know if I quite followed, if you mean that you want to check if the contents of identically named mp3-files differ, you could use the diff tool, like below, but the logic for finding all the identically named files and feeding them to the diff you need to figure out yourself

```
# copy and rename the .mp3 files that are not identical but have the same name
# ...
DIFF=$(diff a b) 
if [ "$DIFF" != "" ] 
then
    echo "The files differ"
fi
# ...
```

There is also the option to use some [tool](http://www.howtogeek.com/201140/how-to-find-and-remove-duplicate-files-on-linux/) that is designed for finding duplicates, like [dupeguru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru/) (Win, Mac, Ubuntu, Arch Linux).